# React Final Form - Field Array - form pristine

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I am using react final form and a react final form array in the form.

The Pristine part of the form is attached to the submit button. However if I open a pre filed in form, remove a value from the array and put the same value back in, the pristine of the form doesn't set back to true even though it is the same, Is there a workaround?